# What is the best approach to configure Docker for a webapp?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jetty

I would like to configure a Docker container for running a Java application that uses Postgres and Jetty.
What is the best approach to do this:

1. Pull three separate containers from the Docker hub and somehow use them together.
2. Create a Dockerfile from scratch with all configurations.
3. Pull three images from the Docker hub and manually create a single Dockerfile from them.

Comment: too vague. This obviously depends on your application, your system, your security demands, etc... and I'm pretty sure you're well aware of this.

Comment: I am just starting to use Docker and I wonder how to configure it to for a simple webapp. Could you at least briefly describe pros and cons of those approaches? Are there any other approach that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point out that all three of your options are sort of valid... In your first option, that "somehow" you are referring to is the [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). Your third option makes sense if you replace *create a single Dockerfile from them* with *create a docker-compose.yml file for them*.

I'm throwing this out there as an answer because I think it will help understanding of how different images can work together. It seems like you were naturally looking for Docker Compose.

Answer (score 0):

A standard layout would be to use 2 containers - one for the database and one for the application (jetty with your Java application - I'm assuming it's a WAR file)

Both should be based on standard containers readily available on Docker Hub.